# Is there an equivalent to finv of Matlab in python?

Tags: python, r, matlab, scipy, statistics

I need to get the Fisher inverse cumulative distribution function for my python econometric project.

Scipy is offering only the Normal inverse cdf.

Do you know about any Fisher inverse CDF in python ?

As it already exists in Matlab, i was wondering if it would exist also in R?

If it dosen't exist in python at least it could be imported from R if it would exist

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SciPy has **lots** of [distributions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html), you're just after their [f distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.f.html), e.g:

```
import scipy.stats as sps

f = sps.f(5, 2)
```

will parameterise it with "d_1=5 and d_2=2".  You can then use this as `f.ppf(0.9)` and get back ~9.3, while `f.cdf(0.9)` will give you ~0.40.

The docs say that `ppf` comes from:

> Percent point function (inverse of cdf — percentiles).

Comment: Yes it's the ppf one that I was looking for. Thank you very much for the link, I just realized how silly was my question. The list of the statistical laws is just not limited. Awesome!

Comment: no probs, everything is obvious in retrospect!  note that it's helpful to mark questions as answered, other users know where to focus their efforts on answering, etc.